# fire a event once the variable data chnages in JQ

Tags: jquery

I want to fire a event once the value of a varible changes. using js or jq not angular.
help me out.
this is a test.

```js
function startTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  seconds = date.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = seconds;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  startTime();
  window.setInterval(function() {
    startTime();
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
#test {
  padding 50px 50px 50px50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>

</div>
```

Help me out on each change of seconds value.

Comment: What is the question? What variable are you trying to watch? Objective could use a lot of clrification

Comment: You know when the second changes. All the times you run the function `startTime` , which could be renamed to `updateTime`. By the way, it could run every 1000ms instead of 500ms.

Comment: i want to fire an event in accordance with the seconds varibable value changing.

Comment: if you are trying to do this on a larger scale, look into `pub sub` libraries and tutorials. Otherwise you really haven't explained on a higher level what your goals are making the question a bit vague. Also not clear why the code you have won't do what you need

Comment: i just need a event to be fired when the variable data chnages form on to another. hope you get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer for now. we cant do it.
have to call it by a function. :(

**EDIT**
The only way is to create a new loop with the same speed the variable will change.
as of here it is 1 second.
so I made another loop with 1 sec interval and executed my function there.
And also in Angular JS it is availble
[Please check this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html) 
Hope it is clear now.
If am wrong., please correct me.
Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend you to edit your answer and re-write it in a more appropriate way with detailed information about **why** it isn't possible. This will help other users that will eventually be looking for the same answer as you.

Comment: "No" is an answer too, and it's good that you did answer your question instead of abandoning it. But I agree with mathielo that a bit more context would be useful for future readers.

Comment: I have added it as per your request.
Thanks